# php function to convert %3c back to html

Tags: php, html

I have a string that needs to be converted back to html. It's in this format:

```
%3cli%3e
```

which should be:

```
<li>
```

What php function can I use to convert this? Tried html_entity_decode() but that didn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)?