# Converting a URL-encoded string to hebrew string

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a string like this: %D7%90%D7%93%D7%99, using PHP.
to Hebrew (so I can use it with MySQL queries).

I've been searching the web & stackoverflow for over 4 hours but found nothing about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php function to convert %3c back to html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822420/php-function-to-convert-3c-back-to-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [URL-encoded (aka percent-encoded)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) string, not "octet string." You simply need to [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it.